# SphereGeometry in threeJs is alpha: false ... is not visible ... how can I see it in my scene?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I have this page: example 1 - http://songnes.com/g/g84.html
and this one: example 2 - https://www.songnes.com/gift/page20.html

both have the same code ( except minor details in html ) but the script in Three js is identical - copy/paste - is the same

Except that in example 1 - you can see the planet ( a sphere rotating with the oval )
and in example 2 - you can not see the planet ( you see the "space" of the planet only )

very strange, can someone help me please to make the planet show in example 2.

Comment: Already answered at the forum: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/a-spheregeometry-is-not-showing-need-help-please/15644

Comment: Thank you for this comment.... but not really. The solution for my problem is still there.... what you guys put is just, what the console is saying... and that is "the problem" we know that is the problem, but I don't know what is "the solution" to that problem or how to fix that problem.... I was in the understanding that this forum was to help people like me learn, maybe I was wrong. I do hope to find someone that will be willing to "help" me, not just tell me what I'm doing wrong... I'm new and willing to learn, I will not get discourage in learning, and I really appreciate all your help

Comment: Sorry, there are many existing resources that tell you what CORS is and how to fix it. Instead of asking for more support,  you should put more effort into research.